# Why can't ARIIA access this device?

Tags: plot-explanation, eagle-eye

In Eagle Eye (2008), the computer ARIIA accesses all the electronic devices during the whole movie. Then why can't she access this small mobile device?

[image]

Comment: Well, that phone looks like a Blackberry, and if memory serves, 2008 was back when Blackberry was actually known for having good electronic security on their devices, so perhaps that's why she couldn't crack it.  It's also possible that RIM was a sponsor for the movie *(I couldn't find any proof of that online, though)*, and so highlighting that the evil military AI can't crack a BB would be their idea of "good product placement."

Comment: @Steve-O I think that's possible. I remember that it was difficult to hack into the elevator system of Burj Dubai in a Mission Impossible movie. But that's odd because in the same movie, they effortlessly hacked into the world's most secure prisons to help Tom Cruise escape. Dubai must definitely be a sponsor.